# How to set UIBarButtonItem created on a child VC to the navigation controller of its parent VC?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I created a custom container view controller. It has two child view controllers. Each one set an instance of UIBarButtonItem to `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` to show the button on the navigation bar. But, nothing showed up.

What is the right way to make it work?

The following code is what I used in `viewDidLoad` of the container view controller.

**UPDATE:**
I marked the only answer here as the right one. @rdelmar is explaining correctly as far as my code concerns. But, here is one thing I'd like to point out. Basically, It's not a good approach to make any child VCs expect the existence of the navigation controller if the children are supposed to be used in the custom controller.
If I could get back in the past, I would have made **some interfaces on the container to let their children know that they can set any navigation items if needed.**

```
[self addChildViewController:childVC];
[self.view addSubview:childVC.view];
[childVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: The navigation controller only looks at the navigation item of its immediate child view controller, which from your description, sounds like the container.  You will need to devise some mechanism to forward changes to the navigationItem of the container's children to the container's navigationItem.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am facing similar problem. And yes navigation item is not nil.

Comment: Same problem here :( No solutions so far?

Comment: @mshrestha Please check out my update. hope that it's helpful for you. If you have any different opinions, please feel free to drop your comment.

Comment: @Banana please check out my additional comment above.

Answer (score 5):

If the parent controller is embedded in a navigation controller, then that parent is the one that will have a navigationItem, not the child. So, self.navigationItem in the child will be nil. You need to reference the parent,

```
self.parentViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ...
```

Comment: Otherwise your mention, I found that self.navigationItem in the child view controller is not nil. And, I don't want to make a constraint that the view controller is supposed to be a child of any container.

Comment: self.navigationItem in the child view controller is not nil.

Comment: It's not nil because, as the documentation mentions, "The first time the property is accessed, the UINavigationItem object is created. Therefore, you should not access this property if you are not using a navigation controller to display the view controller."  Though it is created it is not hooked up to the NavigationBar.